# facebook graph image size

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have noticed, playing with facebook graph that they have no longer the settings for enlarging the profile image of the user/his friends and it remains 50x50.
all attempts to change the number, add `?type=large` or  `?type=full_image` and so on returned an invalid link.
does anyone know if the feature was eliminated altogether or is there simply another way?

more in details:
When I search in graph API explorer `me?fields=picture`
I get the URL https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c0.1.50.50/p50x50/1148963_10201325993408291_1462479970_n.jpg?oh=c64e3d731c38903477bbbaffdfb86146&oe=5B40A546 
note the p50x50 in the url
the image is indeed at a size of 50x50px

attempt to change the number to 100x100 for instance leads to `Invalid URL signature` error reply

also an attempt to add `?type=large` or  `?type=full_image` sufix to the image or change the URL in any way.
the height and width params are basically getters- `me?fields=picture{height,width}`
and not setters as they were in the tutorials from 2014.
trying to follow the tutorials
`me?fields=picture{height(100),width(100)}`, it leads to Invalid URL signature` error reply in the browser.

Comment: Works fine for me. What exactly do you mean by “invalid link”, invalid how?

Comment: thank you for your reply, I have edited the question to be more clear about what i mean

Comment: _“ttempt to change the number to 100x100 for instance leads to Invalid URL signature error reply”_ - of course it does, you were never supposed to do that anyway. _“also an attempt to add ?type=large or  ?type=full_image sufix to the image or change the URL in any way”_ - that parameter needs to be appended to the original API call, not the CDN image URL ... Mark’s profile pic in small, 50x50: https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture And in large, 200x200, by simply applying the parameter as described in the documentation: https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large